# Insert/copy file in Google Drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

Dropbox has Copy_ref api makes uploading same file to multiple users easy. I can't find this kind of feature in Google Drive api. Is it possible to upload same file to different user's account using copy instead of uploading from my server?

Answer (score 0):

i think there's no way to do that. instead you can use  share capability which Drive SDK have.  with share you can create a copy of file into others account.

```
 private static Permission insertPermission(Drive service, String fileId,
  String value, String type, String role) {
Permission newPermission = new Permission();

newPermission.setValue(value);
newPermission.setType(type);
newPermission.setRole(role);
try {
  return service.permissions().insert(fileId, newPermission).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
}
return null;
```

were setValue is for specifying the user account, type isfor account type(user or group), and role is the privilege. you can refer to this [Drive Permission](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert)